# Regex: Select all words that doesn not have . (dot) in front of them

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have 5 cases:

`I search something in my-life.html" again>`

`Don't trust mylifehtml" ever>`

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

`<!--<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" >`

`<html lang="en-US" xmlns:og="schema/">`

I want to use regex to find all words that doesn not have . (dot) in front of html, that means **The Output must be** `Don't trust mylifehtml" ever>`

So, I need to find that words that have html, but doesn't have .dot before html.

I made a regex, but is not good:

SEARCH: `^.*((?!\.).+html">)`

Comment: According to your request `I need to find that words that have html, but doesn't have .dot before html` (words or line?), all the lines except the first one meet this constraint.

Comment: hi @Toto Yes, can be both versions. To be sure. Important is, from my example, to find only the world `mylifehtml"` from the line `Don't trust mylifehtml" ever>`. Actually, I want to find all links that doesn't have [dot] in front of html.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. `<!DOCTYPE html>` doesn't have a dot before `html`, why shouldn't it match?

Comment: yes, exactly I don't want to match this line `<!DOCTYPE html>` I wanna match only the words such as  `mylifehtml"` (without digits) or the entire line that contains words such as `mylifehtml"`.

Comment: Well, I think something like: `\w+html\b` to match only 1 word or `^.*\w+html\b.*$` to match the whole line.

Comment: almost good, except your both regex finds also words like `/xhtml` . So punctuation such as `/()\<>?-+=&$#@` must be eliminate, otherwise all of my files will be find at searching.

Comment: Well, it's hard to understand your real request, why `mylifehtml` is valid and `xhtml` is not? May be `(?:^|\h)w+html(?:\h|$)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131324/discussion-between-just-me-and-toto).

Answer (score 0):

**This solution will find only the lines that contains `html` but doesn't have** `.html`:

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*html)(?:(?!\.html).)+$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**This solution will find only the lines that doesn't have** `.html`:

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!.*\.html).*$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

@Toto:

SEARCH: `(?:^|\h)\w+html"`

**OR:**

SEARCH: `(?:^|\h)\w+html.+?(?:\h|$)`

**OR:**

SEARCH: `^(?=.*https://)(?:(?!\.html).)+$`